# Emacs, namespaces and defuns

Tags: emacs, elisp

The only thing I don't like about Emacs is the lack of namespaces, so I'm wondering if I can implement them on my own.

[This](http://6e5e5ae9206fa093.paste.se/) is my first attempt, and it's obvious that I can't just replace every match of a name with its prefixed version, but what should I check? I can check for bindings with (let) then mark the entire subtree, but what if somebody creates a (my-let) function that uses let? Is my effort destined to fail? :(

Also, why are my defuns failing to define the function? Do I have to run something similar to intern-symbol on every new token?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by namespaces in a text editor that is Emacs?  Or is it the language elisp that you are actually referring to?

Comment: Given that elisp lacks namespaces, and the question links to some elisp code and asks about elisp forms and functions like `let`, `defun`, and `intern-symbol`, I think it's safe to assume that the question is about elisp.

Comment: @vpit3833: That looks pretty nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding namespaces will take more than prefixing the identifiers with the namespace names.  The interpreter has to be able to tell the namespaces.  Some tinkering must go into the interpreter as well.  That might need to go through a thorough discussion at gnu.emacs.sources and/or #emacs at irc.freenode.org.

Comment: No, he uses a macro, and the interpreter expands macros just as well as the compiler, so his approach can definitely work.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the first google result for `elisp namespaces`...

There's a minimalist implementation of namespaces called [fakespace](https://github.com/skeeto/elisp-fakespace) which you can get on elpa, which does basic encapsulation. I'm working on something ambitious myself, which you can check out [here](https://github.com/chrisbarrett/elisp-namespaces).

Comment: Both fakespace and your namespaces rely on side-effects rather than relying on scoping.  From that point of view, I much prefer vpit3833's approach.

Comment: Yeah, I get _very_ funky with side-effects. But I'm coming from an opinionated position: I'm trying to monkey-patch a bit of immutability onto Elisp and make package authors document their public interface explicitly.

Comment: @Chris: I was thrilled when I saw the idea of your namespaces. But that immutability is actually something I do not want. It will only lead to copy-pasting code if people want to change some immutable variable, and that will lead to community maintenance hell. Instead I would prefer a way to just mark something as private. Like namespace/-fun: If it starts with -, it’s private.

Comment: I'd like to make sure I understand your point. My package mangles private symbols to encourage privacy. Are you saying you'd prefer it did not do so in some cases?

Comment: Yes. I don’t like it when developers try to make the private stuff inaccessible. I would prefer just defining an infix which tells other developers that those parts are not part of the external API. No need to shackle others if you can advise them.

Comment: after all, you cannot actually enforce anything if people can access your code. So there’s no point in trying (and risking collateral damage). In proprietary space that might make sense (enforce restrictions on your users), but here, where everyone can read the source with `C-h f <function>, C-x C-o C-s in \`RET`, that’s just encumumbrance, I think.

Comment: @ChrisBarret: Besides, I added a note for your suggestion.

Comment: It's clear this isn't the package for you then. :) It's not about 'shackling' users (such loaded terms you use). It's about promoting encapsulation by giving devs the option to have namespaced stuff. This could be very useful in concurrent situations, where you want guarantees of immutability and privacy for your vars.

Comment: I use the loaded term, to emphasize the problem :). Why do you want guarantees of immutability and privacy for your vars, if someone else uses them? The user of your library might have perfectly valid reasons for violating those guarantees, so to me the wish to forbid changes seems to be motivated by fear instead of seeking advantages.

Comment: Essentially you get all the advantages you seek by just marking a variable as private, so other developers see that it might not be safe to change these.

Comment: The difference between namespaced and inaccessible is `foo/bar` vs `foo/mmietcrsieh`. And the difference between private and inaccessible can be `foo/-bar` vs. `foo/mmietcrsieh`. I much prefer `foo/-bar` (or just `foo--bar`).

Comment: SO comments aren't the best place for this. You're welcome to file an issue on the GitHub repo if you want to continue this discussion. :)

Comment: So you would be open for an option to mark as private instead of mangling?

Comment: I'm open to being convinced. :)

Answer (score 3):

To handle things like `my-let` or `my-defun`, you need to macroexpand those definitions, e.g. with `macroexpand-all`.

For the failure to define the functions, you need to use `intern` instead of `make-symbol` (because `make-symbol` always creates a new distinct fresh uninterned symbol).

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed version of the code from @vpit3833 to provide namespace support (using the hint from @Stefan). It’s too good to leave around half-fixed :)

```
;; Simple namespace definitions for easier elisp writing and clean
;; access from outside. Pythonesque elisp :)
;; 
;; thanks to vpit3833 → http://6e5e5ae9206fa093.paste.se/

(defmacro namespace (prefix &rest sexps)
  (let* ((naive-dfs-map
          (lambda (fun tree)
            (mapcar (lambda (n) (if (listp n) (funcall naive-dfs-map fun n)
                                  (funcall fun n))) tree)))
         (to-rewrite (loop for sexp in sexps
                           when (member (car sexp)
                                        '(defvar defmacro defun))
                           collect (cadr sexp)))
         (fixed-sexps (funcall naive-dfs-map
                               (lambda (n) (if (member n to-rewrite)
                                               (intern
                                                (format "%s-%s" prefix n)) n))
                               sexps)))
    `(progn ,@fixed-sexps)))

;; (namespace test
;;            (defun three () 3)
;;            (defun four () (let ((three 4)) three))
;;            (defun + (&rest args) (apply #'- args)))

;; (test-+ 1 2 3)

(provide 'namespace)
```

Comment: Chris Barrett suggested adding `(declare (indent defun))` to the macro, so the code does not get indented that deeply after declaring a namespace. I like the deep indent, though - but I also do not have enough reputation to accept it and adapt it to show it as option (commented out).

Comment: Well, this won't work. What you actually need is a so-called code-walker. The code-walker is a piece of Lisp code, which actually understands Lisp syntax. You need to walk the code and replace function calls and/or variable names. But only those. (macroexpand '(namespace test (defun test () 'test))) -> The last test should not be changed.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://www.merl.com/publications/TR1993-017/ (Macroexpand-All)

Comment: the code actually works, though. It definitely has weaknesses (and it would be really cool if you could fix it to work in general instead of just working for simple cases), but it provides a feature I was missing a lot when writing Emacs Lisp.

Comment: What does it mean, 'it works'? It rewrites not only functions, but also variables and data. Looks like a bug to me. `(namespace test (defun foo (a) (cond ((eq a 'foo) t) ((eq a 'bar) t) (t nil))))`. Now `(test-foo 'bar)` returns t, but `(test-foo 'foo)` returns nil?

Comment: “It works” means, if I avoid certain usages, the code I enclose in (namespace) gets a namespace. Do you have code for a short code-walker which does the simple namespacing - but in a clean way?

Comment: Also rewriting variables sounds right to me (these should be namespaced, too), but the rewriting of 'test sounds wrong - like a bug, yes.